# Not able to login in symfony2 via HTTP but HTTPS working

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I have below configuration in my security.yml file

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/form, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: https }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

And i am able to login but when i change back to http. for eg:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: http }
    - { path: ^/form, roles: ROLE_USER, requires_channel: http }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: http }
```

**or**

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/form, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I don't get any error message and login does not happen.

Please let me know what could be the issue. And i am not using any cache but i cleared the cache and restarted server.

```
metadata_cache_driver: array
query_cache_driver: array
result_cache_driver: array
```

Please help me what could be the issue.

**EDIT 1**

```
security:
    firewalls:
      secured_user_area:
        pattern: ^/(forms|account)
        provider: user_one
        context: session
        anonymous: ~

        form_login:                 
            check_path:  login_check 
            login_path:  login
            default_target_path: dashboard
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:
            path:   logout
            target: login

        remember_me:
            name: _rem_me
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 86400
            path: /
            domain: ~

      secured_admin_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        provider: user_two
        context: session
        anonymous: ~

        form_login:                 
            check_path:  admin_login_check  
            login_path:  admin_login
            default_target_path: admin_dashboard
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

        logout:
            path:   admin_logout
            target: admin_login

        remember_me:
            name: _rem_me
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 86400
            path: /
            domain: ~

      public:
        pattern: ^/
        context: session
        anonymous: ~

      admin_login:
        pattern: ^/admin/login
        context: session
        anonymous: ~

      dev:
          pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
          security: false
          #anonymous: ~
          #http_basic:
          #    realm: "Secured Demo Area" 

    providers:
        user_one:
          entity: { class: Achme\UserOneBundle\Entity\UserOne, property: mobile }

        user_two:
          entity: { class: Achme\UserTwoBundle\Entity\UserTwo, property: email }

        #in_memory:
        #  memory:
        #    users:
        #      user: { password: userpass, roles: ['ROLE_USER'] }
        #      admin: { password: admin, roles: ['ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'] }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Achme\UserOneBundle\Entity\UserOne: { algorithm: sha512, encode_as_base64: false, iterations: 10 }
        Achme\UserTwoBundle\Entity\UserTwo: { algorithm: sha512, encode_as_base64: false, iterations: 10 }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH] 

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/form, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: Can anybody answer please?

Comment: did you clear your cache after changing the values?

Comment: Yes i have cleared the cache. As i am using array as shown above but still i have cleared cache and restarted server. i am able to login when i use https but not in http

Comment: I have updated my symfony2.4.2 to 2.4.4 also but still this issue persist. I am not getting error on page. i am running on dev mode. no log in symfony2.. How is this possible for http only. working in https  but not in http.

Comment: Obviously i was talking about `app/console cache:clear --env=dev` (or prod) and additionally clearing any opcode cache like `apc` or `opcache` as we are dealing with configuration-cache and not any result-caches. Do you get a blank page or what does it mean that you "don't get any error message" when trying to login? Is nothing sent in return ? What status code is returned if any?

Comment: add your firewall configuration and the login-route definition to the question please.

Comment: Nobody is helping on this. :(

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide enough information to diagnose the problem ... please add the login route definitions admin_login, admin_login_check, login and login_check to the question as i requested before. I already asked wether you get a blank page and which status code you get, too.

Comment: @nifr Thank you, for you reply. I have answered n resolved. Now i can go home. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue

In Config.yml file was the issue

I have changed following parameter

```
  cookie_secure: true
  cookie_httponly: true
```

**TO**

```
  cookie_secure: false
  cookie_httponly: false
```